# What's the optimal way to store image data temporarily in a containerized website?

Tags: python, flask

I'm currently working on a website where i want the user to upload one or more images, my flask backend will do some changes on these pictures and then return them back to the front end.

Where do I optimally save these images temporarily especially if there are more then one user at the same time on my website (I'm planning on containerizing the website). Is it safe for me to save the images in the folder of the website or do I need e.g. a database for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a database, or external object storage like Amazon S3.

I say this for a couple of reasons:

**Accidents do happen.**  Say the client does an HTTP POST, gets a URL back, and does an HTTP GET to retrieve the result.  But in the meantime, the container restarts (because the system crashed; your cloud instance got terminated; you restarted the container to upgrade its image; the application failed); the container-temporary filesystem will get lost.

**A worker can run in a separate container.**  It's very reasonable to structure this application as a front-end Web server, that pushes messages into a job queue, and then a back-end worker picks up messages out of that queue to process the images.  The main server and the worker will have separate container-local filesystems.

**You might want to scale up the parts of this.**  You can easily run multiple containers from the same image; they'll each have separate container-local filesystems, and you won't directly control which replica a request goes to, so every container needs access to the same underlying storage.

**...and it might not be on the same host.**  In particular, cluster technologies like Kubernetes or Docker Swarm make it reasonably straightforward to run container-based applications spread across multiple systems; sharing files between hosts isn't straightforward, even in these environments.  (Most of the Kubernetes Volume types that are easy to get aren't usable across multiple hosts, unless you set up a separate NFS server.)

That set of constraints would imply trying to avoid even named volumes as much as you can.  It makes sense to use volumes for the underlying storage for your database, and it can make sense to use Docker bind mounts to inject configuration files or get log files out, but ideally your container doesn't really use its local filesystem at all and doesn't care how many copies of itself are running.

(Do *not* rely on Docker's behavior of populating a named volume on first use.  There are three big problems with it: it is on first use only, so if you update the underlying image, the volume won't get updated; it only works with Docker named volumes and not other options like bind-mounts; and it only works in Docker proper and not in Kubernetes.)

Other decisions are possible given other sets of constraints.  If you're absolutely sure you will never ever want to run this application spread across multiple nodes, Docker volumes or bind mounts might make sense.  I'd still avoid the container-temporary filesystem.

Comment: Thanks alot for your detailed answer, I'll probably upload them to a database as you said, this will also make it easier for my flask backend. Sorry but i can't give you an upvote yet because I just joined stackoverflow ^^